# How to get current date and time from server in android app?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, time

I am developing an android app for learning purposes. I need to get the current date and time from my server to my android app and set restrictions so that the app can be accessed only during the specified date and time (say, Monday to Wednesday, from 10:30 am to 3 pm for a specific time-zone). And I don't want to use device date and time because it can be changed and the app can be accessed.

I checked out `SntpClient` code and implemented it in my app but got no success.

Comment: refer this link http://androidexample.com/AsyncroTask_Example_To_Get_Server_Data_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=59&aaid=84 it may help you :)

Answer (score 3):

- write a simple endpoint on your server that just simply returns a long value representing millisecond
- write a simple http client to make a request to that endpoint from android client, alternatively pass some tokens with that request to know what device/client/user is accessing, alternatively add secure communication here
- parse that `String` to `Long` and `Long` to `Date` in android  client

Answer (score 0):

in php code use  `$my_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

for current date and this output is parse in android application

Answer (score 0):

To help get you started…

Create a [Java Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) on your web server running a Servlet container, such as Apache Tomcat or Eclipse Jetty. Instead of a full web page, the servlet merely returns a string with the date-time in standard ISO 8601 format in UTC time zone (no time zone offset). Add the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library to avoid using the notoriously bad java.util.Date/Calendar.

Heart of the servlet…

```
String now = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ).toString();
```

Use a HTTP client library on the Android side to call the servlet.

Heart of the client side code…

```
DateTime start = new DateTime( 2013, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime stop = start.plusHours( 8 );
DateTime now = new DateTime( stringReturnedByServlet, DateTimeZone.UTC );
if ( now.isAfter(start) & now.isBefore(stop) ) {
  // Do your thing
} else {
  // Refuse to do your thing
}
```